# Can i run multiple instances of my background worker?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, loops, listbox, backgroundworker

I have an app which contains a listbox full of directory paths.

I'm looping through each of the directory paths and pulling out the permissions set on each path.

I had this as a function at first, called like so...

```
 For Each dirpath In ListBox3.Items
     CalculatePermissions(dirpath)
 Next
```

This works, but of course my app would hang and go unresponsive for a long period whilst the work was being carried out. I'm looking recursively at all directories and subdirectories, so there can be alot of results.

I changed the function to a backgroundworker and tried calling it asynchronously like so...

```
 For Each dirpath In ListBox3.Items
     bgw_CalcPermissions(dirpath)
 Next
```

I grabbed the dirpath argument in my bgw with this...

```
 Dim path As String = CStr(e.Argument)
```

This worked a treat... the app does not hang and the directories are looped through... problem is that it only works for the first path in the listbox. All the rest are skipped, because the backgroundworker is busy and cannot process.

Is it possible to spawn multiple instances of the background worked to carry out the work, or should I be approaching this in a different way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would highly recommend that you take a look at the TAP pattern for asynchronous programming in .NET, which has been around since .NET Framework 4.5.  It uses the `Task` class, along with the `Async` and `Await` keywords to make asynchronous code much easier to read and maintain.

However, even with using the background worker, you could still do this easily by calling the `Parallel.ForEach` method.  To do that, you'd first need to change it so you send the full list of items to the background worker, rather than the single item:

```
Dim paths As IEnumerable(Of String) = ListBox1.Items.OfType(Of String).ToArray()
bgw_CalcPermissions(paths)
```

Then, in the background worker event handler, you can call `Parallel.ForEach` like this:

```
Dim paths As IEnumerable(Of String) = DirectCast(e.Argument, IEnumerable(Of String))
Parallel.ForEach(paths, AddressOf CalcPermissions)
```